# How to write this String i/p "I love coding" to >> o/p "I1 love4 coding6" without using toCharArray method?

Tags: java, string

Basically after every word there attach the sum of the number of character of the following word.

*WITHOUT USING toCharArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to build a new `String` with Regular Expression matching and a `StringBuffer`.

```
String in = "I love coding";
StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(in);
while (matcher.find()) matcher.appendReplacement(out, "$0" + matcher.group().length());
matcher.appendTail(out);
```

This will fill `out` with `"I1 love4 coding6"`, which can be accessed with `out.toString()`. In addition to simplicity, it has the added benefit of preserving punctuation, so that an `in` of `"I, love coding!"` will yield an `out` of `"I1, love4 coding6!"`.

Note: if I've far overthought this, and the scope of your project defines the "words" as all entities separated by spaces, i.e. in the sentence `"coding... is fun"`, the "words" are `"coding..."`, `"is"`, and `"fun"`, then you can still use this procedure, swapping out the `"\\w+"` in `Pattern.compile` with `"[^ ]+"`. `"I, love coding!"` becomes `"I,2 love4 coding!7"`.

Answer (score 1):

- Split the string.
- Append the length of each string to each splitted string.
- Join the strings.

A simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "I love coding";
    String[] words = test.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];
        words[i] = word + word.length();
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        builder.append(word);
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    String result = builder.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: please explain with an example :)